# KeyboardEvent.altKey is false on keydown event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome 76 on MacOS 10.14, running on a MacBook Pro laptop.

#### Objective

I'm trying to create a hotkey for a web application, using a two-key chord.

#### Actual Result

Using the code below, I am consistently receiving a `false` value, when I press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key == 'u') {
    txt.value = e.altKey.toString()
  }
})
```

**NOTE**: `txt` is a `<textarea>` HTML element.

#### Expected Result

The `KeyboardEvent.altKey` attribute returns `true` when <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> is pressed on the `keydown` event. According to the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation for the `altKey` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey), it should return `true` under these circumstances. The current documentation doesn't specify that it shouldn't work with the `keydown` event.

**Question**: What is going on here, and how do I get this working the way I expect?

Comment: Instead of the keyDown method, try keyPressed--or to analyze it try dumping all the events you can get to the console to see exactly what they do.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> was actually returning the character `¨` instead of `u` for the `key` attribute. Instead, what I needed to do was check the `code` attribute of the `KeyboardEvent`, and check that it was equal to `KeyU`.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code == 'KeyU' && e.altKey) {
    // Do stuff here
  }
})
```